# how can i remove part of my url in browser

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my current link : 
http://localhost/htaccess_url/home.php?pnlk=adindex.

I want to show url like this : http://localhost/htaccess_url/adindex.

I have tried by htacces. My code is :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ home.php?route=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ home.php?route=$1
```

Please help me. I am new in this area.

Thank you.

Comment: hmm , you change url right?

Comment: @S Sopno: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ home.php?pnlk=$1 [L]
```

but note that, you route url , it mean the old url still working
routing `http://localhost/htaccess_url/home.php?pnlk=adindex`

into

`http://localhost/htaccess_url/adindex`

hope this help

Comment: Mohsen Shakibafar, Bro if i use this code in my htacces file it gave me Internal Server Error. I have kept my htaccess file in root directory.

Comment: Brother , i use this code into my htacces file. But it doesnt work. My url still remain as like old one. plz help

Comment: @SSopno , try new edit , after that enter `http://localhost/htaccess_url/adindex` in URL